# Non constant and non monotonic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If  $S = <a,b,c>$ is a sequence which is neither constant nor monotonic, does it imply that its element $b$ holds either its maximum or minimum value?

Thank you

Comment: $S = <1, 2, 2>$?

Comment: It's a monotonic sequence, right?

Comment: It depends on if the problem needs strict monotonicity or not.

Comment: In this case, I need to avoid both strictly monotonic and constant sequences.

Comment: Ok, then $<1, 2, 2>$ is neither strictly monotonic nor constant.

Comment: Agree. I'm looking for a way to get sequences where b is either greater or lower than both a and c, as  <1,2,1>, <1,2,0>, ...., <1,0,1>, <2,1,3>.